# Calculate Distance of a Traversed Path Using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

The requirement is to track user's coordinate and end of the day find out the driver kilometer.

What I am doing

Step 1: Record all coordinates that device receives

Step 2: Encode all the coordinates to a polyline encoded string

Step 3: Using Distance Matrix API, calculating the distance between the source and the encoded polyline

The problem is, when I receive the response from Distance Matrix API, it seems it is giving me the response of source and every coordinates encoded in polylines which I am not sure that it will take consideration of the entire path or not.

I tried to read the documentation but it didn't help. Does anyone have the similar problem earlier?

// Get the encoded path and find the distance

```
let source      = coordinates.remove(at: 0)
let polyline    = Polyline.init(coordinates: coordinates)
let encodedPath = polyline.encodedPolyline
requestCalculateDistance(forSource: source, encodedPath: encodedPath)
```

// Response from distance Matrix API

```
rows =     (
                {
            elements =             (
                                {
                    distance =                     {
                        text = "0.1 km";
                        value = 135;
                    };
                    duration =                     {
                        text = "1 min";
                        value = 4;
                    };
                    status = OK;
                },
                                {
                    distance =                     {
                        text = "0.1 km";
                        value = 135;
                    };
                    duration =                     {
                        text = "1 min";
                        value = 4;
                    };
                    status = OK;
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) of Google Maps JavaScript API in order to solve your problem.

As you mentioned you collect all coordinates that form a polyline, so you have an array of LatLng objects. In order to calculate the length of the polyline you can use the `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength()` method that accepts `Array<LatLng>` or `MVCArray<LatLng>` as a first parameter.

Have a look at the documentation for further details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#spherical.computeLength

I hope this helps!